# apex chart semi donut with custom custom indicator

Tags: javascript, apexcharts, gauge

Hello I have the following design That I have to implement. I am using **apexcharts** as a chart library in my application .

[image: required design]

I could not find any **gauge/indicator** related information of `apexchart` while googling and now
quite not sure weather it is possible to implement the chart as required design.

2 important elements on my design

1. custom indicator
2. rounded edges of the arc

Do you have any idea that could help me here ?

Thank You.

```js
var options = {
  series: [44, 55, 41, 17, 15],
  chart: {
    type: "donut"
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      startAngle: -90,
      endAngle: 90,
      offsetY: 10
    }
  },
  grid: {
    padding: {
      bottom: -80
    }
  },
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      options: {
        chart: {
          width: 200
        },
        legend: {
          position: "bottom"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<div id="chart"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is one in Echarts i use it before

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=gauge-progress

Comment: Instead of just linking a resource, add a summary of its important points in case the resource stops being hosted there in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Since the author of ApexChart confirmed they cannot build the one like this at https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/771

So I suggest you this library. It has a similar one you need
https://antoniolago.github.io/react-gauge-component/

[image]